# Chess set for championships

Tags: chess-set

I would like to buy a chess set used in championships of the highest quality.
How are chess sets classified ?
I do not want a recommendation but rather a trade mark.

Also, I do not know what means this:

Color : A

Color : B

? What color is recommended and what is the difference between color a and b ? ?

Comment: do u mean dgt board?

Comment: Yes. BTW what is the difference between USB and BlueTooth board, which one is better ?

Comment: Belated answer. They use electronic DGT boards and pieces. DGT company also offers non-electronic versions.  "Timeless pieces"(brown and yellow) are used at high level events, and the board used is the DGT Walnut board. Also, "the official FIDE set" pieces (black and white) have recently been introduced and are now also used at high level along with timeless pieces. You can get pieces from other brands. And you don't need electronic versions (for broadcasting). As to the board, you can get a non-electronic Walnut board by DGT = you will have precisely the same as at top events.

Comment: Important. If you want your set to be precisely the same, you need to make sure pieces are of the right size. The pieces currently used at top events are those with 3.75'' king height (both the timeless and the so called "FIDE official set" pieces.) Note, pieces and boards are usually sold separately. And the FIDE official set is just a set of new style pieces that I personally don't like very much. Don't buy electronic versions. They are 3 times more expensive and you don't need them unless for an official broadcast when the position is transmitted from the board automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Championship boards

For international or continental championships, FIDE's regulations state that wooden boards should be used¹. Additionally they ought to be electronic chessboard that autosense moves and interface to chess clock and computers; here, look for the DGT prefix.

¹ FIDE rules, 3.1. Material and colour: For the World or Continental top level competitions wooden boards should be used. For other FIDE registered tournaments boards made of wood, plastic or card are recommended. In all cases boards should be rigid.

## Colours A and B

A stands for the dark, B for the light colour. Common dark-light combinations are black and white, brown and white, green and lime, ultramarine and azure, as well as buff and cream. Opinions differ on what combination is best; many prefer a pastel green and lime for its ease on the eyes.
The main thing is to have a high contrast between dark and light squares to help colourblind players.

## Piece set

Recommended are DGT pieces that are styled in a variation on the staunton model, that is with a robust knight. Top notch is to supply an additional third knight, bishop and rook as well as a second queen for each sides promotions.

## Trade mark links:

(tbc)

[House of Staunton](https://www.houseofstaunton.com)

[Chesshouse](https://www.chesshouse.com)

[Digital Game Technology DGT](https://digitalgametechnology.com)

Comment: Please, why are most products [here](https://dgtshop.com/products/chess-boards) sold out ?